# How to print out line in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to test the return value of this function getFileExtension(input.files[0].name)  (I have a comment there to point at that line)
My question is how to print out that value in javascript? Thanks!

```html
<script>
    function getFileExtension(filename) {
        var ext=filename.split('.').pop();
        return ext
    }
</script>

<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);"> 

<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        if (getFileExtension(input.files[0].name)=="png") { // this line is our problem 
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById("pdf").innerHTML="<img id='blah' src=" +
                                       e.target.result + " alt='your image' width='450'>"
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `console.log(ext);` or whatever. The output appears in the browser console.

Comment: Or, if you want something that works across all browsers, you could use the old stand-by: `alert(input.files[0].name);`.

Comment: or you can do document.write

Answer (score 7):

You can print out values in javascript by writing

```
console.log(value);
```

Most browsers have a console which you can see by pressing `f12`. The values will end up there.

If you are using Internet explorer remember to have developer tools open (f12) or you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
var msg = 'value: ' + yourVar;
if (console) {
    console.log(msg); // or console.info(msg) or whatever
} else {
    alert(msg);
}
```

Personally, I wrote a simple lightweight console so I can output to any div on a page.  I did that instead of a lot of `document.write` as Avitus suggests in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Firebug plugin for Firefox for more detailed error descriptions and in order to see the values plugged into console.log(value)

Answer (score 0):

You could make predefined tests to ensure that your function gives the correct output in different situations:

```
function test_getFileExtension() {
    test("foo.png", "png");
    test("bar.py", "py");
    test("the_really_long_name.txt", "txt");
    test("playlist.xspf", "xspf");
    test("%20.txt", "txt");
    test("file_without_extension", ""); // actually gives an error

    function test(input,output) {
        var o=getFileExtension(input);
        if (o === output) {
            console.log("OK: "+input+" --> "+o);
        } else {
            console.log("ERROR: "+input+" --> "+o);
        }
    }
}
```

Then as soon as you update your function, you call `test_getFileExtension()` again and make sure that it still work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to print out line in Javascript.
I'm listing few methods which works really well.

```
let a = 23;

console.log(a) // 23
process.stdout.write(a) //23
alert(a) //23
```

each of them would give the same result. Happy coding Cheers.

Comment: Note that `process.stdout.write` only works in node, and `alert` only works in the browser.